# Centos 7 firewall-cmd settings not persisting

Tags: nat, centos7, gateway, firewall-cmd

I have decided to do a bit of spring cleaning, and am doing a refresh of some of my underlying infrastructure.

One of the critical components I am overhauling is the Network Gateway server. I updated my Test Environment (which is an identical, but lower power copy of my Production Environment), and all worked well, but when I applied the same to my Production system, the firewall-cmd rules do not persist between reboots.

I have to run the following commands at startup:

```
# firewall-cmd --remove-interface=eth0 --zone=public
# firewall-cmd --remove-interface=eth1 --zone=public
# firewall-cmd --remove-interface=eth0 --zone=public --permanent
# firewall-cmd --remove-interface=eth1 --zone=public --permanent
# firewall-cmd --add-interface=eth0 --zone=external
# firewall-cmd --add-interface=eth1 --zone=internal
# firewall-cmd --add-interface=eth0 --zone=external --permanent
# firewall-cmd --add-interface=eth1 --zone=internal --permanent
# firewall-cmd --complete-reload
```

At which point normal service is resumed. When I run `# firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` after reboot, both of the interfaces have left the `internal` and `external` zones, and have returned to the `public` zone.

Can someone shed some light on why these settings are not persisting?

Comment: Incidentally, I have now nuked the system and started over with a blank OS, and have done exactly what I did before and now the configuration persists as expected

Answer (score 1):

Changes made with `firewall-cmd` are only persistent when you (also) make them persistent with `--permanent`...

[**`man firewall-cmd`**](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora20/man1/firewall-cmd.1.html)

> **--permanent**
>   The permanent option `--permanent` can be used to set options
>    permanently. These changes are not effective immediately, only
>    after service restart/reload or system reboot. **Without the
>    `--permanent` option, a change will only be part of the runtime
>    configuration**.
>   ...
>   If you want to make a change in runtime and permanent
>   configuration, use the **same call with and without** the `--permanent` option.

Comment: But that's the problem. They AREN'T being persisted when I use the `--permanent` flag. When the system is rebooted, the configuration resets. However, when the configuration is reloaded, it remains intact.